# documentdb returns empty object from null values

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am calling something similar to the following code against a documentdb collection:

```
List<DocumentCollection> collectionList = documentClient
                .queryCollections(
                        getTodoDatabase().getSelfLink(),
                        "SELECT * FROM root r WHERE r.id='" + COLLECTION_ID
                                + "'", null).getQueryIterable().toList();
```

The json that I am returning has null on certain fields, which is fine, but when I return the collectionList the nulls are converted to empty JSON objects; for example:

```
"`content`" : `null` is converted to "`content`" : `{}`
```

Does anyone know if there is a way around this?

Comment: Not answering your actual question (yet) but just a note; you don't need to use self-links anymore. you can now address  resources using their actual ids. 

so, instead of getTodoDatabase().getSelfLink() which would return something like 'dbs/reifh343==' you can now refer to the database with the link 'dbs/todo'. Much easier, and saves you a query operation

Comment: Just to confirm, this is the Java SDK, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Add a WHERE clause specifying the type you are expecting using the type checking functions

IS_ARRAY, IS_BOOL, IS_NULL, IS_NUMBER, IS_OBJECT, IS_STRING, IS_DEFINED, and IS_PRIMITIVE